# when two curves are **transverse**?

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, curves, mapping-class-group

in the "A Primer on Mapping Class Groups by  Benson Farb and Dan Margalit" we define intersection number as follow :

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be a pair of **transverse**, oriented, simple closed curves in $S$. Recall that the algebraic intersection number $\hat{i}(\alpha, \beta)$ is defined as the sum of the indices of the intersection points of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, where an intersection point is of index $+1$ when the orientation of the intersection agrees with the orientation of $S$ and is $-1$ otherwise. Recall that $\hat{i}(\alpha, \beta)$ depends only on the homology classes of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. In particular, it makes sense to write $\hat{i}(a, b)$ for $a$ and $b$, the free homotopy classes (or homology classes) of closed curves $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

> what is mean of **transverse** ? when two curves are **transverse** ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversality_(mathematics)

Comment: @MoisheKohan so two curves (in $\mathbb R^2$)are **transverse** iff they have not same tangent line in all point  ? is this true ?

Comment: I would rather say: "in all intersection points"...

Comment: At all intersection points their tangent lines should span the tangent plane.

Comment: The rule of thumb that I use (in great simplification) is to see transverse as non-parallel